# How can I get ActiveRecord to bind in raw statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm basically doing this:

```rb
::OuterModel.where(%{
  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inner_model 
           WHERE outer_model.id = inner_model.outer_model_id)
             AND inner_model.parameter = ?)
}, 1)
```

Now the issue becomes that this does text replacement in ActiveRecord, it doesn't bind `?` to `1`, which in turn is rendering ActiveRecords prepared statements pretty meaningless since every query has a different value of `1`.

How can I get bind on my `EXIST` statements?

This is also of course true when doing something simple like:

```rb
::OuterModel.where('state = ?', 'active')
```

The alternative here isn't to do `.join` or generate `IN`, the performance of that is *much* worse, or wouldn't work in my actual use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I'm able to achieve this using `arel.exists`, rails will then prepare and bind with the OuterModel query.

```
inner_models = ::InnerModel.where("outer_model.id = inner_model.outer_model_id")
                           .where(paramter: 1)
::OuterModel.where(inner_models.arel.exists)
```

Although it doesn't really answer the in-general question on binding against raw SQL.

Comment: It may be a safety issue. In Rails 6 I think they're trying to require us to use Arel for any raw sql

Comment: `OuterModel.find_by_sql(OuterModel.where('state = $1'), [[nil, 'active']])`